# tikz: Shifting a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm new to tikz so any advice appreciated.
I have the following tree, but I need the FP node to be an the same level (vertically) as the price node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [level distance=10mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=32mm, edge from parent/.append style= {solid}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=16mm, edge from parent/.append style={solid}},
%level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,level distance=12mm, edge from parent/.append style={solid}}, grow=right]

\scriptsize
\node {price}
child {node (one) {P}
}
child{node (two) {F}
child {node (down) {FP}
    }
};
\draw (one) -- (down);
\end{tikzpicture};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

and code, of course:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    level distance = 12 mm,
  sibling distance = 32 mm,
                    ]
\scriptsize
\node {price}
    child[grow=right] {node (down) {FP}}
%    
    child[grow=south west]  {node (one) {P}}
    child[grow=south east]  {node (two) {F}}
    ;
\draw[red] (one) -- (down);
\end{tikzpicture};
```

Comment: For some reason, using `grow` messes up the level and sibling distances. Any workaround for that?